# "Суперэкономпредложение" или "супер-эконом-предложение"?

Tags: словообразование, дефис, слитно-дефис, приставка, слитно

Слово «суперэкономпредложение» пишется слитно или с двумя дефисами? "Грамота.ру" говорит, что всё, что с «эконом», пишется слитно. Значит, слово должно быть длинным вот таким вот?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сочетание «**суперэконом**» весьма востребовано в современном языке, и оно уже часто используется как **несклоняемое приложение.**

**В орфографическом словаре РАН**:  эконом... – первая часть сложных слов в знач. «экономический, экономичный», пишется слитно, но: ***эконом-такси, эконом-тур, эконом-уровень.***

Итак, появляются исключения для тех сочетаний, где ***эконом*** и ***суперэконом*** являются **приложениями** с дефисным написанием, а не сокращением слова «экономический».

Я думаю, что корректное написание будет таким: **суперэконом-предложение.**

Как и **суперэконом-тур** по Японии https://darkwren.ru/yaponiya/superekonom-tur-po-yaponii/

**Примечание.** Слитное написание «суперэкономпредложение» попросту не читается, а форма с двумя дефисами выглядит несколько странно.

Comment: М-да, Sharon, теперь я сомневаюсь в правильности своих рассуждений, хотя пытался опираться только на правила, без самодеятельности... Надо задать вопрос "Грамоте.ру".

Comment: В этой теме многое изменилось, с тех пор как были составлены классические правила. Появилось много новых слов и словосочетаний, которые не нормированы в должной мере и уж тем более не объяснены.  Вероятно, для составителей Правил письма это первоочередная задача. К примеру, зкономкласс и преимум-класс пишутся по-разному (Грамота это подтверждает), а почему? Хорошо бы это понимать, а не только заучивать.

Comment: "Грамота.ру" подтвердила, что корректно слитное написание.

Comment: Именно этого слова - суперэкономпредложение? А ссылка у вас есть.

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ ссылкой, конечно же.

Comment: Но там "суперэкономкласс", а в этой теме индивидуальный подход к каждому слову. Суперэкономкласс еще можно прочитать, к тому же слово дублирует "экономкласс".  Но суперэкономпредложение прочитать уже невозможно, да и слово "экономпредложение" как-то  редко встречается.

Comment: Так-то да, слово другое. Задам им конкретно про "суперэкономпредложение". Но всё равно, почему так сложна эта тема(((

Comment: Запись слова должна отвечать самым общим правилам. Предлагаю на досуге подумать о смысловой значимости каждой формы письма :)) Запись слова должна отвечать правилам в каждой конкретной теме (сложные существительные),  но при этом учитывать индивидуальные особенности каждого слова (фонетики, значения, области применения). Поэтому всегда  есть исключения.

Comment: Ой, спасибо за дискуссию... Уже думала, никто не подискутирует над моим вопросом....

Comment: Sharon, "Грамота.ру" мне ответила, что всё-таки пишется слитно. Дополню этим свой ответ: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=309698

Comment: @Shi Komarishe
Спасибо за информацию. Формализм решения по заданной схеме мне понятен. Но это еще не словарь., а "МЫСЛЕФОРМЫ" Грамоты.ру К примеры, слово "суперэконом" применяется как самостоятельное слово довольно часто, например тариф "Суперэконом". Но в словаре его нет, а люди из Грамоты пока еще замечают только приставку "супер"  и решение  дают по этой приставке. Практика письма расходится с мнением Грамоты.ру, вот это пока надо считать фактом и желательно знать пользователям языка. Так что выбор за ними.

Comment: Если человек — редактор, ему важно опираться на правила и авторитетное мнение ("Грамота.ру" всё же авторитет), чтобы в случае спорных моментов уметь объяснить свой выбор читателям  и коллегам по работе с книгой (выпускающий редактор, переводчик, корректор и пр.)...

Comment: Это да, если редактору важно опираться, и это для него главное. Вот вы спросите об этом у тех, кто "суперэконом-тур по Японии" неверно пишет. Может, для них что-то другое важнее. Здравый смысл, например,  или красивая и четкая графика сайта. Ну чтобы вы в Японию к ним поехали, а не еше куда.

Answer (score 1):

Разберёмся пошагово.

1. Определим, приставка "супер" пишется слитно или через дефис (см. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3985)).

> 7. На общем основании иноязычные приставки анти-, архи-, гипер-, интер-, инфра-, контр-, пост-, суб-, супер-, транс-, ультра-, экстра- и др. <...>

Итак, в обычной ситуации приставка "супер" пишется со словом слитно: супергерой, суперскидка, суперпредложение и т. д.

2. Уточним, есть ли аналогичные примеры в языке и как пишется эта приставка в сложных словах (см. [здесь](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=287761)).

> Приставка *супер...* пишется слитно (например: *суперсобытие*). Но если вторая часть слова содержит дефис *(онлайн-событие*), то слитное написание заменяется дефисным и возникает написание с двумя дефисами: *супер-онлайн-событие.*

Поэтому мы написали бы, к примеру: супер-мини-компьютер, супер-макси-юбка, супер-пупер-диско-шар и пр. (см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8/)).

3. Выясним, как пишется слово, к которому стыкуется наша приставка: есть в нём дефис или нет.

Оказывается, что "эконом" — это не какая-то иноязычная приставка, а сложносокращённое слово от "экономичный", поэтому пишется слитно: "экономпредложение" (= "экономичное предложение"), как и "экономмагазин", "экономкласс" и т. д. (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords?layout=item&id=25_247)).

**ВЫВОД**

Поскольку на общем основании приставка "супер" пишется слитно, а наш случай не подпадает под правило о дефисном написании приставки при наличии дефиса во второй части слова ("экономпредложение" пишется без дефиса), то всё наше слово следует писать слитно: **суперэкономпредложение**.

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге подтвердила правильность слитного написания, это соответствует правилам (хотя словарной фиксации этого слова нет), см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=309698) и [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309690).